# How to pull data from Jenkins API to Google Sheet

Tags: api, jenkins, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I want to retrieve data via Jenkins API using Google Sheet Script and store it in Google Sheet**

1) Pull Jenkins Job Builds using Jenkins API to Google Sheet - **DONE**
2) Store data to Google Sheet **???**

*(need only "builds.subBuilds.buildNumber" and "builds.subBuilds.duration" values)*
*(need to correct mistake in the script)*

```
    function getJenkinsBuilds() {

    // get the jenkins job

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://jenkins.[domain].co/job/Build+Deploy/api/json', {
        'method': 'get',
        'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
        'headers' : {'Authorization' : 'Basic [tokan]'},
      });

      // parse the json reply and return builds

      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      var builds = data["builds"];
      Logger.log(builds);
      return builds;
      };

      // store predefined parameters from builds in the spreadsheet

   function setDataToTable() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Jenkins');
        var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");

        var rows = [['buildNumber','duration'],['','']];      // I GUESS THE MISTAKE IS HERE?

        sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn(), rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
   }
```

**Actual result:**

```
Log shows retrieved array with Builds objects, i.e.:  

[19-10-10 16:18:16:937 AEDT] [{number=2081, subBuilds=[{jobName=...  

'Jenkins' spreadsheet is empty.
```

**Expected result:**

```
Store "builds.subBuilds.buildNumber" and "builds.subBuilds.duration" values  
in the Google Sheet ('Jenkins' spreadsheet), i.e.:  

buildNumber duration
123         15sec
456         16sec
...         ...
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. But I have to apologize my answer didn't resolve your issue. I could understand that my answer was not useful for your situation. So I would like to delete it, because I don't want to confuse other users.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it working in the next way:

```
function getJenkinsBuilds() 
{

      // get jenkins builds
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://jenkins.[domain].co/job/Build+Deploy/api/json', {
      'method': 'get',
      'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
      'headers' : {'Authorization' : 'Basic [token]'}
      });

      // parse the json reply
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      var builds = data["builds"];
      var number = data['builds'][0]['number'];
      var url = data['builds'][0]['url'];
      Logger.log(number);
      Logger.log(url);

      // fill in the spreadsheet with data
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Jenkins');
      var cell = sheet.getRange('A1');
      var rows = [['BUILD']];

              for (var i = 0; i < builds.length; i++)
              {
              var number = data['builds'][i]['number'];
              var url = data['builds'][i]['url'];
              rows.push(['=HYPERLINK("'+url+'","'+number+'")']);
              Logger.log(number);
              Logger.log(url);
              sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn(), rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
              }
};
```